# PostSharp Aspects: Accessing "injected" properties in Entity Framework LINQ Queries

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, postsharp

I'm using PostSharp aspects to "inject" properties into some classes, and those classes will be stored (code first) in a DB by Entity Framework. Later on, I'd like to query and access the injected properties of each class in queries.
For example, say I'm writing an aspect that injects an "id" property into objects:

```
interface IIdentifyable
{
    string id { get; set; }
}

[IntroduceInterface(typeof(IIdentifyable))]
[Serializable]
public class IdentifiableAspect : InstanceLevelAspect, IIdentifyable
{
    [Key]
    [IntroduceMember]
    public virtual string id { get; set; }

    public override void RuntimeInitializeInstance()
    {
        id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        base.RuntimeInitializeInstance();
    }
}

[Serializable]
[IdentifiableAspect]
public class Car
{
  // ...
}
```

Now I want to use the "injected" id property of the Car class in entity framework linq queries. Say for example I'd like to count all cars whose id contains the number 1.
I've tried several methods, none of which works:

```
// Throws exception
// LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method IIdentifyable Cast[Car,IIdentifyable](car) method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
dbContext.cars.Where(car => Post.Cast<Car, IIdentifyable>(car).id.Contains("1")).Count();

// Throws exception
// IIdentifyable is not a valid metadata type for type filtering operations. Type filtering is only valid on entity types and complex types.
dbContext.cars.OfType<IIdentifyable>().Where(car => car.id.Contains("1")).Count();

// Throws exception
// Unable to cast the type Car to type IIdentifyable. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitives or enumeration types.
dbContext.cars.Where(car => ((IIdentifyable)car).id.Contains("1")).Count();
```

Is there any way to do this, or no way at all to use PostSharp in conjunction with EF that particular way?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the generated `Car` have `id` column in the database ?

Comment: Yes, it does. The database generation works (surprisingly) fine and exactly as intended.

Comment: You'll need to define your classes in a seperate assembly. I don't think you can use injected properties in the same project where you apply the aspect because I beleieve PostSharp happens post compiliation. You'll need to do your Linq stuff in a new project that will reference the compiled output.

E.x.:
ProjectA  <-- define your aspects here
ProjectB <-- define your classes here. Make it reference ProjectA
ProjectC <-- Define your linq queries here

YOur other alternative is to use the dynamic keyword and lose your compile type checking.

Comment: Ah, putting the classes into a separate assembly should work! Thanks for the idea.  Just out of further curiosity - I've tried finding a solution with the dynamic keyword as well, but I don't think that one works in LINQ queries right?

Comment: @hjb417, you could post it as an answer

Comment: In case other people read this in the future - hjb417 has mentioned this, but I think it makes sense to point out specifically. If the project defining the classes is part of the same solution as the project using them, do not reference the project, but rather the compiled assembly. By referencing the project, you won't get proper intellisense and you may receive compiler warnings/errors all the way (even though actually compiling everything works as well that way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure of your project setup, but I'll make the assumption everything is in the same project:

You'll need to define your classes in a seperate assembly. I don't think you can use injected properties in the same project where you apply the aspect because I beleieve PostSharp happens post compiliation. You'll need to do your Linq stuff in a new project that will reference the compiled output.

E.x.:
ProjectA <-- define your aspects here
ProjectB <-- define your classes here. Make it reference ProjectA
ProjectC <-- Define your linq queries here

Your other alternative is to use the dynamic keyword and lose your compile type checking.

Comment: Yes, exactly. PostSharp processes the assembly after C# compiler is done and thus C# cannot know about the weaved stuff.